# Twitter API. How to get authenticated user's tweets that is filtered?

Tags: twitter

In my iOS application I need to show user's tweets that contains a specific hashtag. In rest api 1.1 there is `users/search` endpoint. But it believe it is not the one that is suitable for this. There is `search/tweets` endpoint but I couldn't create the right query for this. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The GET search/tweets is the right endpoint to use to search for tweets using a specific hashtag. Twitter launched Fabric a month ago, a SDK that implement API calls natively.

You can check how to do API calls here:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/api

An example:

```
// Objective-C
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"id" : @"20"};
NSError *clientError;
NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                         URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                         URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                         parameters:params
                         error:&clientError];

if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
     sendTwitterRequest:request
     completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                  NSData *data,
                  NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data) {
            // handle the response data e.g.
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:0
                                  error:&jsonError];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
        }
    }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use search api (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) with required query. For eg.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Ascreen_name

where screen_name is the screen_name of the user whose tweets you want.